# Mock process env in React Vite project for Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, vite

In order to use .env variables in my project, i have import it in vite.config.ts file like

```
export default {
    define: {
        'import.meta.env.APP_ENV': `"${process.env?.ENV?.toLowerCase() ?? 'prod'}"`
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        exclude: ['types']
    }
};
```

And in my components i am using `const APP_ENV = import.meta.env.APP_ENV;` to access the variables.

This is working fine, now i am adding test cases and rendering the component directly but the APP_ENV is undefined

I tried to pass process env in beforeEach like

```
beforeEach(() => {
   process.env?.ENV = 'LOCAL'
})
```